# When should I use a material over a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I'm starting to make models in blender and I created few object which I want to import to my game in Unity. I have very simple graphics(basicaly one colour for each part of the object) and I don't know if I should use either material or texture. I've searched for the anserw but I haven't found anything against using materials. What should I choose? Please note that performance is aleso important for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your objects will only have solid colors then a material will suffice.  If you want your objects to have some sort of pattern like tiger stripes or a logo then you will want to learn how to use textures.  Large texture files can affect performance, but on today's computers you can have a lot of textures before you will notice performance problems.

Comment: Actualy I'm creating an app for android. So you say that materials are more performance friendly than textures(in case of one color)?

Comment: In general, yes.